# Drain too high water pooling around it

Tags: drain

My husband installed a new Moen faucet.  The drain appears to be raised more than the old drain which is causing the water to stand around the drain. Is there any fix for this?

Comment: Pictures are always worth a thousand words.

Comment: Is the seal in the right place?

Comment: what does a faucet have to do with a drain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are usually a few different rubber seals or gaskets that go on the drain pipe before installing it into the sink. Make sure to use the thinnest one so the drain will be low. If you did use the thinnest one and the drain is still too high, get some plumbers putty from your home store and form a bead of it and wrap that around the drain instead of the rubber seal and then install the drain pipe. You should be good to go. stay safe where ever you are.